# Delphi XE5 Acces Violation on app start

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

On two computers is ok, on three there is the same exception with the same addres for AV. Thank for help

```
begin
  Application.Hinthidepause := 30000;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm3, Form3);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm4, Form4);
  Application.Run;
end;
```

```
exception class    : EAccessViolation
exception message  : Access violation at address 00405361 in module 'Project1.exe'. Read of address 00000064.

main thread ($1d44):
00405361 +3d Project1.exe System         75  +0 SysGetMem
00406827 +3f Project1.exe System         75  +0 @ReallocMem
0040c38c +d8 Project1.exe System         75  +0 DynArraySetLength
0040c4bd +05 Project1.exe System         75  +0 @DynArraySetLength
005465af +23 Project1.exe System.Classes        {System.Generics.Collections}TList<System.Generics.Collections.TList<System.Classes.TComponent>>.SetCapacity
005466b0 +2c Project1.exe System.Classes        {System.Generics.Collections}TList<System.Generics.Collections.TList<System.Classes.TComponent>>.Grow
005466d2 +16 Project1.exe System.Classes        {System.Generics.Collections}TList<System.Generics.Collections.TList<System.Classes.TComponent>>.GrowCheck
00546a4d +0d Project1.exe System.Classes        {System.Generics.Collections}TList<System.Generics.Collections.TList<System.Classes.TComponent>>.Add
0051e75e +36 Project1.exe System.Classes        BeginGlobalLoading
0051e8de +46 Project1.exe System.Classes        InitInheritedComponent
0064cfde +c6 Project1.exe Vcl.Forms             TCustomForm.Create
00657ffa +76 Project1.exe Vcl.Forms             TApplication.CreateForm
00883ce7 +c7 Project1.exe Project1  54 +13 initialization
76a13368 +10 kernel32.dll
```

UPDATE
Problem was with this procedure:

```
procedure KopiujRTF(const Source, destination: TRichEdit);
var
  rtfStream: TEditStream;
  sourceStream: TMemoryStream;
  function EditStreamReader(dwCookie: DWORD; pBuff: Pointer; cb: LongInt;
    pcb: PLongInt): DWORD; stdcall;
  begin
    Result := $0000;
    try
      pcb^ := TStream(dwCookie).Read(pBuff^, cb);
    except
      Result := $FFFF;
    end;
  end;
begin
  destination.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  sourceStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Source.Lines.SaveToStream(sourceStream);
    sourceStream.Position := 0;
    destination.MaxLength := destination.MaxLength + sourceStream.Size;
    rtfStream.dwCookie := DWORD(sourceStream);
    rtfStream.dwError := $0000;
    rtfStream.pfnCallback := @EditStreamReader;
    destination.Perform(EM_STREAMIN, SFF_SELECTION or SF_RTF or SFF_PLAINRTF,
      lParam(@rtfStream));
    if rtfStream.dwError <> $0000 then
      zolty := True;
    sourceStream.Free;
    destination.Lines.EndUpdate;
  except
  end;
end;
```

On form1 create i had:

RichEdit1.MaxLength := $7FFFFFF0;

after enabling Range check debugger highlited this:

```
destination.MaxLength := destination.MaxLength + sourceStream.Size;
```

Removing max length for RichEdit resolved problem. Thanks for Yours help.

Comment: Your call stack suggests that a nil `TList` pointer is being accessed during DFM streaming.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, that's an erroneous analysis. The AV would occur be long before that. It would occur as `TList<T>.Add` read `FCount` in order to form the parameter to pass to `GrowCheck`.

Comment: The AV is at a low enough address to indicate a nil pointer is being accessed somewhere.  If `Add()` is called on an invalid `TList<T>` then obviously its `FCount` is not going to hold a valid count, and it is going to call `SetLength()` on an invalid dynamic array.

Comment: @Remy The call stack is blatantly for a heap corruption. Surely you recognise that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call stack indicates that you have corrupted the heap in some other part of your program. That's the explanation, with probability > 0.999, for an access violation in `SysGetMem`.

You'll need to look at what happens during startup, before the code in this call stack is executed. Look for buffer overruns, that is accessing out-of-bounds array elements. It is very likely that merely enabling the indispensible [range checking](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Range_checking) feature will be enough to locate your program's defect.

Comment: Thank You for answers. Will try, one problem is that on my computer all works fine.

Comment: That's quite common with heap corruptions. They are often not repeatable. You have to use range checking, at the very least for debugging builds. It's a truly wonderful feature.

Comment: I always wonder why people keep this off during development - especially when an error occurs.

Comment: @UweRaabe I guess because people aren't aware of it. Why don't Emba enable it by default in the debug config?

Comment: well i enbaled range checking in project's option, but all is ok.

Comment: Well, you'll have to keep digging. Try stripping out code until the problem goes away, if you cannot do it statically.

Comment: one thing i noticed after "range checking" that updating text in RichEdit doesnt work. No errors, just no new text. On uncheck this option all works good back.

Comment: Ok, i checked this in debugger mode and problem is solved! i had on form create RichEdit1.MaxLength := $7FFFFFF0 and later in code i have destination.MaxLength := destination.MaxLength + sourceStream.Size; and here was ERangeError exception. I was lucky cause normally dont use RichEdit function in my app. Once again thanks!!!

Comment: +1 for recommending range checking.  The first time I enabled it in a project I nearly had a heart attack, and then spent several hours wondering why mode code had **ever** worked.  Indispensable.

Comment: @user3075132 It's not clear how that would lead to a heap corruption. Remember that not all heap corruption's are found by range checking. Range checking may not reveal your problem.

Comment: BTW The same goes for Overflow checking, it should also be On. I set both on by default and never bother turning them off. The price of not catching weird results caused by range/overflow errors is just too high IMO

Comment: @David Heffernan I checked if now is ok on computers when problem occured and now no acces violation.

Comment: unfortunelty i made some changes and still the same errors. Now i moved all code to TForm1.Show and no errors.

Comment: heap corruption is hard to debug. I never believed that rich edit thing was the cause. Full debug fastmm could help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found that the problem is in the definition of the version.
When I opened the version info, I found that the version was not included and I couldn't include it.
The solution was to recreate the configuration of construction.